# How to split text based on start and end text in Java

Tags: java, string

I have to read a file as below and split the text into String array using start and end tag of texts.
The file consists of multiple XMLs for same XSD.

need to take each xml value and add to a string array.

```
<Message
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <ID>29576</ID>
        <SchemaVersion>466</SchemaVersion>
    </Header>
</Message>

<Message
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <ID>295476</ID>
        <SchemaVersion>466</SchemaVersion>
    </Header>
</Message>

<Message
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <ID>29s576</ID>
        <SchemaVersion>466</SchemaVersion>
    </Header>
</Message>
```

i need to split the ablve text based on start tag(`<Message>`) and end tag(`</Message>`)

Please let me know how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have `<Message>` in the text. And what result are you expecting? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: You should use a parser to interpret the contents of an XML file. Splitting should only be used to reformat the XML file, but not to interpret it's content, or read it to an array.

Comment: @ernest_k : Start tag <Message
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: @TreffnonX : My input file is a text file, which consists multiple xml text inside. I need to take each XML content and do something with the content. Looking for easy and efficient way to extract the XML parts.

Comment: @SuddhasattaDhar Then wrap the content in a new tag, so there is a common root. That way you can parse it. Just replacing stuff inside is very fragile, because strings could potentially contain tags themselves.